# EXP-00085 warnings while doing full backup

Tags: oracle, export

During a full export of my Oracle 10.2.0.2 database, I encounter the following warnings

```
[...]
. exporting post-schema procedural objects and actions
EXP-00008: ORACLE error 6502 encountered
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHED_MAIN_EXPORT", line 351
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHED_JOB_EXPORT", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1
EXP-00085: The previous problem occurred when calling     SYS.DBMS_SCHED_JOB_EXPORT.create_exp for object 102269
EXP-00008: ORACLE error 6502 encountered
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHED_MAIN_EXPORT", line 351
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHED_JOB_EXPORT", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1
EXP-00085: The previous problem occurred when calling SYS.DBMS_SCHED_JOB_EXPORT.create_exp for object 102271
EXP-00008: ORACLE error 6502 encountered
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHED_MAIN_EXPORT", line 351
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHED_JOB_EXPORT", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1
EXP-00085: The previous problem occurred when calling SYS.DBMS_SCHED_JOB_EXPORT.create_exp for object 102273
. exporting user history table
. exporting default and system auditing options
. exporting statistics
Export terminated successfully with warnings.
```

I looked for these three objects querying dba_objects with their object_id and it returns

- ADV_SQLACCESS5150248
- ADV_SQLACCESS9067727
- ADV_SQLACCESS2676493

Are these warnings worrying?

How should I fix them and what is going on exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect this is bug 5120780 fixed in 10.2.0.4 (a quick search on Metalink would have told you).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I probably would have find it on metalink should I be able to login, but our previous DBA left with the Customer Support Identifier needed to create an account... We are struggling to get it back. I'm an interim DBA trying to do his best..!

Comment: Good luck! You should have an account manager at Oracle who can retrieve it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Gaius is correct.<sup>+1</sup>  In case someone else has this problem in the future, it is known to occur on 10.1.0.2 to 10.2.0.3 on any platform.  In addition to upgrading to 10.2.0.4, Patch 5120780 can be applied to fix this problem.  The patch is available for a limited set of platforms.